# Unable to add a header to NSMutableRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempURL]] autorelease];
[request setValue:encryptedValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"EncString"];
```

I could spot all other headers in the request but this specific header is missing, can any one let me know what could be the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code:

```
NSString *tempURL = @"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701101/unable-to-add-a-header-to-nsmutablerequest";
NSString *encryptedValue = @"whatever_that_has_no_special_characters_or_values_that_would_make_you_think_it_is_relevant_to_reproduce_this_issue";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempURL]];    
[request setValue:encryptedValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"EncString"];
NSLog(@"%@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
```

The output is:

```
{
    EncString = "whatever_that_has_no_special_characters_or_values_that_would_make_you_think_it_is_relevant_to_reproduce_this_issue";
}
```

which looks good. There is no reason to suspect the code you provided is responsible for the issue. Maybe you should check one of the following:

- Is `encryptedValue` truly a valid object to be placed into header (is string, not too long, no very special characters)
- Is the object you are printing really this specific request (printing `NSLog(@"%p", request);` returns same result)
- In no place in this object a herder is being removed (if nothing else subclass `NSMutableURLRequest` and override relevant methods to track what is going on)

If none of these work create a post with additional details on what you have done, where are you checking these headers and "could spot all other headers".

Comment: I have used a tool called burp suite to figure out network calls. there i could spot all the headers. This code resides in a dynamic library which is packed in ipa. For all the applications it is able to add that header. only for this app it is not able add. I couldn't get what could be the reason.

Comment: Yes encryptedValue is a true object, it is same across all the applications. In all other applications it is working but not in this.